# Ble gatt services

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am newbie for the ble. I want to know one thing. The ble product developed using the company's gatt services is good practice or not. What I mean is The ble service using the 16 bit characteristics rather than the ble using the 128 bit characteristics which is best to move

Thank you,
Navin

Comment: 16 bit UUID shuld be used for well-known or reserved (Bluetooth Defined) GATT services. For custom service it is much better to use 128 bit unique UUIID.

Comment: You may find the following article useful: https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/ as it explains about choosing UUID for a custom service.

Comment: You'll probably find what you need in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017350/bluetooth-gatt-service-uuid-overview/60100785 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541760/how-to-find-handles-corresponding-to-different-uuids-of-ble-devices/57542647#57542647